# Speed of convergence of integral

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to find out how fast or slow $f(x)$ should decay as $x \to 0$ and $x \to \infty$ so that the integral below always converges.

$\int_0^{\infty}{\frac{f(x)}{x}} dx$

Comment: Assuming that $f$ is a $C^1[0,+\infty)$ function, sufficient conditions are $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to +\infty} x^\delta f(x)=0$ for some $\delta>0$.

Comment: The integral is absolutely convergent iff $f(e^x)\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.